# jquery, string, find

Tags: jquery, string

HI,

Can somebody help me with this :

This is my HTML:

```
    <div class="Breadcrumb">
       <a href="#">Home</a>&nbsp;&gt;&nbsp;
       <a href="#">Projects</a>&nbsp;&gt;&nbsp;
       Projects Text
    </div>
```

I want to get with jQuery the string what is not in anchor tag , in this example is "Projects Text"

Theoretically something like this

jQuery :

```
var name = $("Breadcrumb (not <a>) ").text();
```

but I don't need this one "`&nbsp;&gt;&nbsp;`"

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but should work:

```
var text = $('.Breadcrumb').contents().filter(function() { 
    return this.nodeType == 3;
});

alert(text[text.length-1]);
```

Comment: it can be  nodeType ==2, or 4 

the number of anchors  are different

Comment: @Alexander Try the code.  nodeType refers to the type of elements.  3 indicates a TEXT_NODE (try `alert(Node.TEXT_NODE);`) as opposed to an ELEMENT_NODE. And then he grabs the last elements in the array (the final block of text).  You may need to strip out some of the markup, but this looks like a good solution to me.

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible, as `&nbsp;&gt;&nbsp; Projects Text` is actually one node within the DOM tree. So you cannot get the `Projects Text` alone without filtering it out. If you know, that the text is preceded by `&nbsp;&gt;&nbsp;`, you could however simply split that out.

Or as MillsJROSS suggested, you need to put the code inside another tag.

Comment: but with this &nbsp;&gt;&nbsp;, I can do that ?

Comment: For example like this: `$( '.Breadcrumb a:last' )[0].nextSibling.nodeValue` – Don't know if there is a better way with jQuery, I don't use it that much.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the text of the "A" tags. You'll need to do some string parsing in javascript to snip out the nbsp bits. I suggest a regex.

```
var foo = $(".Breadcrumb a").text();
```

Comment: That's not what he wants. He want's the `Projects Text`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest changing the HTML to the following...

```
<div class="BreadCrumb">
    <a href="#">Home</a>&nbsp;&gt;&nbsp;
    <a href="#">Projects</a>&nbsp;&gt;&nbsp;
    <span class="your_class_name">Projects Text</span>
</div>
```

Then with Jquery you could just do the following...

```
var name = $(".BreadCrumb .your_class_name").text();
```

Comment: Accidently typed in HTML instead of HREF in the anchor tags. This is now fixed.

Answer (score 0):

@poke is correct. Change your html:

```
<div class="Breadcrumb">
   <a href="#">Home</a>&nbsp;&gt;&nbsp;
   <a href="#">Projects</a>&nbsp;&gt;&nbsp;
   <span>Projects Text</span>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var name = $(".Breadcrumb span").text();
```

**EDIT:**

If you can't or won't change the html and your breadcrumbs are consistent, then you can use a regex to get rid of whitespace and anything before and including the `>`:

```
var name = $(".Breadcrumb").text().replace(/(^\s+|\s+$|(.*)>\s*)/g,"");
```

I still think, if you have control over the html generation, that adding the extra `span` tag is cleaner with the extra bonus of allowing you to easily style the current page with css.