# Remove special characters in string with Regexp-jQuery

Tags: jquery, regex, string

Who can help me with regular expression? I need to remove a part of a string with jQuery, but I don't have much experience in regex.

```
<div class="test" >
    &nbsp;&gt;&nbsp;&nbsp;&gt;&nbsp;Test Text
</div>
```

I want to remove `&nbsp;&gt;&nbsp;&nbsp;&gt;&nbsp;` and to leave just the text.

Comment: Could you please use more descriptive titles.

Comment: See my edit to your previous question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374579/jquery-string-find/2374759. Submitting a new question which is basically a reframing of your previous problem is redundant. You should edit and continue to follow your first post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('.test').html($('.test').html().replace(/&[^;]+;/g, ''))
```

Comment: it is adding \n\n\n at the end

Comment: I answered this in your previous question. `.text().replace(/(^\s+|\s+$|(.*)>\s*)/g,"")`

Comment: Color me skeptical, but is the code you're testing against identical to what you have in your question?  This code can't even introduce new characters, it only replaces matches with empty strings.

Comment: if @ghoppe is right, it sounds like you *already* had the line breaks there.

Comment: @theraccoonbear The line breaks follow the text before the ending `</div>` tag. Your regex doesn't take that into account. So Alex used poor phrasing. It's not adding anything. It's just not removing what he wants removed. :)

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
$('.test').html(function(i, old) { return old.replace(/&(nbsp|gt);/g, ''); });
```

**EDIT**: [Demo](http://jsbin.com/alequ/edit)